# convert function operator from c# into vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

How convert function operator from c# into vb.net,
If i have this code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sd = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string sKey = sd.Single(kvp => kvp.Value.Equals("A value")).Key;
```

how to convert it to vb.net?
I am trying to get the Key name from a dictionary list

Comment: First, the code has nothing to do with "pointers". Second, what does "access through a pointer" mean? .NET doesn't use pointers and member access is the same in both languages. The statement is very simple, have you tried to convert it to VB.NET? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one should do

```
dim sd as new Dictionary(of string, string)()
dim sKey = sd.Single(function(kvp) kvp.Value.Equals("A value")).Key
```

as you can see it's basically just adding `dim` (usually instead of `var`), removing the `;`, changing `<...>` into `(of ...)` and `=>` into `function(...) ...`

Answer (score 0):

Carsten already answered you, but with these conversion problems you can always look at this [online conversion tool](http://converter.telerik.com/).

For your code the tool gives:

```
Dim sd As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
Dim sKey As String = sd.[Single](Function(kvp) kvp.Value.Equals("A value")).Key
```